# How to batch delete using bulkUpdate

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, orm

I have a common User / Role setup, with a user_role join table. I'm trying to use Spring's HibernateTemplate to mass delete all locked users like this:

```
getHibernateTemplate().bulkUpdate("delete from User where locked=?", true);
```

If the user being deleted does not have any roles (no record in the user_role table), then everything goes fine; however if the user does have a role record, I'm getting the following error:

> integrity constraint violated - child
>   record found

Roles are defined in User.java like this:

```
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinTable(name = "user_role", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "user_id") }, inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id"))
private Set<Role> roles = new HashSet<Role>();
```

So how can I batch delete users even if a user has child records? Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Bulk delete operations are not cascaded to **related entities** as per the JPA specification:

> #### 4.10 Bulk Update and Delete Operations
>
> Bulk update and delete operations
>   apply to entities of a single entity
>   class (together with its subclasses,
>   if any). Only one entity abstract
>   schema type may be specified in the
>   FROM or UPDATE clause.
>
> ...
>
> A delete operation only applies to
>   entities of the specified class and
>   its subclasses. **It does not cascade
>   to related entities**.

However, I'd expect the JPA provider to deal with join tables. Sadly, Hibernate doesn't and this is logged in [HHH-1917](http://opensource.atlassian.com/projects/hibernate/browse/HHH-1917). I'm afraid you'll have to fall back on native SQL to clean up the join table yourself or to use cascading foreign keys in the schema.

Answer (score 2):

Application-level cascading (cascading through hibernate annotations or JPA annotations) only work if the actual entity is actually loaded from the db. When you use the hibernate template with HQL, you'll notice that the entities are not loaded, and the HQL is directly converted to SQL to be executed.

If you want to batch delete you have to use an HQL query to delete all relevant tables (ie roles) before deleting the parent table data.

Comment: What would be the HQL to delete records from user_role table, which is not a Hibernate Entity? I'm not terribly familiar with HQL. Thanks!

Comment: You cannot use HQL to manage non-mapped entities. I would advise you to map the user_role table first; the alternative is to use plain SQL to delete from the user_role table.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure because it's hard for me to recreate this problem, but I think you might need to add a cascade to your @ManyToMany

```
@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
```

Comment: I tried and it didn't work.. I also tried @Cascade(org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.DELETE_ORPHAN), didn't work either.

Comment: No, a bulk delete does not cascade to related entities per JPA specification.

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to bulk delete something that have a ManyToMany related items, you first have to delete the relation (in the join table), or do a loop and for each item, delete manually (insane and too much heavy).

So, since JPQL does not allow to do it, a possible way is to make a **native SQL query** for deleting the id you want in the related table, and then, do the bulk delete.